# SQL server 2008 trigger before insert

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I am very new to `SQL` and sorry for asking this is very primary knowledge. My issue as follow.

I have a table called **Group** and `minimumVal` and `maximumVal` are two columns. `minimumVal` always should be less than `maximumVal`. I want to check this before inserting a new record to the table. If this condition failed data should not inserted into the DB.

So as per my understanding I though of having a trigger but have no idea how to write this.

This is what I write so far;

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Group
ON Table_Group
for INSERT
AS  
????
```

Please advise me.

Comment: A better solution in this case is a [`CHECK` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.100).aspx). And SQL Server has no before triggers, only [INSTEAD OF triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=sql.100).aspx).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recommend you use [check constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_Group ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Group
    CHECK (minimumVal < maximumVal)
```

If you still want to use triggers, then you need an [`INSTEAD OF` trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Group ON Table_Group
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO dbo.Table_Group
    SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE minimumVal < maximumVal
END
```

Comment: Thanks.It worked. I used `check constraints `. Is there is any way to set action(eg: display error message) if the check constraint fails.

Comment: @NewDeveloper - A trigger could check for data violating your rule and use [RaIsError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592(v=sql.100).aspx) to indicate its displeasure.